# Android support multidex library implementation

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, dex

I have hit the magic dex limit because my application uses a lot of jars (drive API, greendao, text to pdf, support.. ).

My current solution was that I literally created a second apk just for google drive which I called from the main apk. But now I found out that android finally supports this with this library. My problem is just that I don't know how to implement it(preferably without gradle). I can't find any good tutorials for it.

Okey I am losing my mind trying to implement this... I have found [this](http://blog.osom.info/2014/10/multi-dex-to-rescue-from-infamous-65536.html)

And I added:

```
 android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

To my manifest file and

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

To my mainactivity.java

Also installed gradle plugin for eclipse, exported gradle to get build.gradle file which I changed to:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':android-support-v7-appcompat')
    compile project(':Sync')
    compile project(':gdrive:google-play-services_lib')
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"


    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src-gen','src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src-gen','src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src-gen','src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src-gen','src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

    dexOptions {
      preDexLibraries = false
   }
}

afterEvaluate {
   tasks.matching {
      it.name.startsWith('dex')
   }.each { dx ->
      if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
         dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
      } else {
         dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
      }
   }
}
```

But The error is still the same :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Blog was the old solution.

With Android Studio 0.9.2 & Gradle Plugin 0.14.1, you only need to:

1. Add to AndroidManifest.xml:

.

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

or

Add

```
MultiDex.install(this);
```

in your custom Application's `attachBaseContext` method

or your custom Application extend `MultiDexApplication`

2. add `multiDexEnabled = true` in your build.gradle

.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Done.

Sorry for my poor English

Related Resources:

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

https://plus.google.com/+XavierDucrohet/posts/1FnzwdcBnyC

Comment: Can I do this in eclipse and not in android studio?

Comment: Currently, no. the ADT plugin for Eclipse is no longer in active development.

Answer (score 16):

There are a few things you have to do,

1- In your gradle you need to specify multidex and add the support library:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
        ...
    }
}

dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
  ...
}
```

2- In your manifest you have to set your application to a multidex application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.package.name">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="com.package.name.my_application">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

3.1- In your application class you have to either extend `MultiDexApplication`:

```
public class my_application extends MultiDexApplication
{
    ...
}
```

3.2- Or Overide the `attachBaseContext()` method:

```
public class my_application extends Application
{
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)
    {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

> **Limitations of the multidex support library**
>
> The multidex support library has some known limitations that you should be aware of and test for when you incorporate it into your app build configuration:
>
> - The installation of .dex files during startup onto a device's data partition is complex and can result in Application Not Responding (ANR) errors if the secondary dex files are large. In this case, you should apply code shrinking techniques with ProGuard to minimize the size of dex files and remove unused portions of code.
> - Applications that use multidex may not start on devices that run versions of the platform earlier than Android 4.0 (API level 14) due to a Dalvik linearAlloc bug (Issue 22586). If you are targeting API levels earlier than 14, make sure to perform testing with these versions of the platform as your application can have issues at startup or when particular groups of classes are loaded. Code shrinking can reduce or possibly eliminate these potential issues.
> - Applications using a multidex configuration that make very large memory allocation requests may crash during run time due to a Dalvik linearAlloc limit (Issue 78035). The allocation limit was increased in Android 4.0 (API level 14), but apps may still run into this limit on Android versions prior to Android 5.0 (API level 21).
> - There are complex requirements regarding what classes are needed in the primary dex file when executing in the Dalvik runtime. The Android build tooling updates handle the Android requirements, but it is possible that other included libraries have additional dependency requirements including the use of introspection or invocation of Java methods from native code. Some libraries may not be able to be used until the multidex build tools are updated to allow you to specify classes that must be included in the primary dex file.

resources: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: Can this be done in eclipse or only in android studio?

Comment: Google has stopped supporting Eclipse ADT. So it is possible to do this with eclipse, but Android Studio is the way forward. I really recommend exporting your project to Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: because my project is 40.000 lines + and includes multiple librarys like greenDAO I am haveing extreme troubles migrating to android studio that is why I would like to do this in eclipse but I ran into a lot of trouble doing that. Do you know the solution for doing this is eclipse?

Comment: I spent 3 days trying to do that without luck and since I am doing this on companys money I just cant loose more time for that. If you have a solution on how to do this in eclipse I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `Step 1, Download android studio.` Step 2, Create a new project in Android studio with the same package name. `Step 3, copy all the classes and resources from the eclipse project folder into the android studio.` Step 4, press the run button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69187/discussion-between-tadej-vengust-and-nicolas-tyler).

Comment: here (https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/support-library/features.html#multidex) it says you should add the multidex lib to you gradle. It doesn't say that you should add Multidex.install(this), as shown by Nicolas. It would be helpful if the Android Dev documentation would add that info :-)  Thanks Nicolas for pointing it out.

Comment: Eclipse it not IDE , it's just text editor . i migrate from eclipse to android studio when give up +65K id . dont lose your time . just migrate .

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#avoid

> If you're minSdkVersion is 21 and above, all you need to do is

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

> if you're minSdkVersion is 20 or below, you need to use the support
>   library

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

**Along with**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

update:

if you're using androidX you can use this:

`implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'`

reference to all google maven, where you can search for google's artifacts:

https://maven.google.com/web/index.html