# I can't build my app because of .dex file error. (Android)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I have a little problem here, if i want to build a APK in Android Studio
i get this error message:

```
Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
```

Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
 com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
 com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
 org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:
     Process 'command '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_77/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I found an answer on StackOverflow that said to compile this dependency in my Gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

but that didn't work.

Here's my Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Check this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925264/android-support-multidex-library-implementation

Comment: Android developers link that you mentioned is covering all the stuff about 64k limit. And yeap, you definitely need to include multidex support library. But at first just enable proguard and have a look how it will help you,

Comment: Please [edit] to show your build.gradle file and we can tell you to remove some huge library. Including many libraries is an anti-pattern in Android development

Comment: On a related note, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698816/gradle-what-is-a-non-zero-exit-value-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Read the second blue box on this page.  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to execute dex: method ID not in \[0, 0xffff\]: 65536](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable multidexing in your application, done by setting the `multiDexEnabled` flag in your `build.gradle` to true. Keep in mind that your minimum SDK version must also be 14 or greater.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Then, configure your Application element within the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your `android { // }` `build.gradle` file:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    incremental true
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

Then in your dependencies, add this:

```
dependencies{
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

**Update**

If you are extending Application in your project, switch to extend this:

```
public class MyApp extends MultiDexApplication{

   //inside here, override

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
       super.attachBaseContext(base);
       MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

Finally, set your application name in the AndroidManifest file as

```
<application 
   android:name=".MyApp">
```

This should save you from this issue; good luck!

Comment: The manifest still needs updated to use the MultidexApplication class. Simply adding the gradle dependency doesn't fix the problem

Comment: You don't need to extend that class, you can directly use in the Manifest. For reference, your extension [doesn't do anything extra](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/multidex/+/master/library/src/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.java)

Comment: This case applies to a situation where you already extend Application class but yes, you don't need to if you have no customer application class