# Test apk multidexed won't run on api-19

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, android-multidex

On my current project our test APK has grown over the 64k method limit.
 We have multidex enabled, so running tests on a device with API > 19 , gives no problems, but on API 19 the runner can't find classes in the second dex file.

I have tried reducing the androidTestCompile dependencies but the biggest culprit is espresso, which I need.

Are there any work arounds for the dex limit on the test APK running on platforms that don't natively support multidex ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android support multidex library implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925264/android-support-multidex-library-implementation)

Answer (score 1):

Prior to Android L, Dalvik runtime is used for executing app code. To get around it, you can use the [multidex support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#multidex).

[Read more here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-pre-l).

Comment: I have multidex enabled and it works for the main apk I can run the application fine even on Dalvik ,but not the test apk can't run the androidTests

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Java` class, which would be your custom `testInstrumentationRunner`.

Put this code into it:

```
public class MultiDexAndroidJUnitRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
        //To make it work on MultiDex environment.
        //https://plus.google.com/+OleksandrKucherenko/posts/i7qZdVEy3Ue
        MultiDex.install(getTargetContext());

        super.onCreate(arguments);
    }
}
```

Open your app's `build.gradle`

Replace existing line:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

with yours custom class:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "com.mypackagename.test.MultiDexAndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Hope it will work