# Gradle gives NullPointerException when building project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Please may someone help me fix this `Gradle` (2.14.1) `NullPointerException` error that has started popping up in my Android Studio (2.2) after it crashed. I'm a newbie, so I don't know how to deal with this.

I've tried:

- cleaning the project
- reinstalling Android Studio and the SDK
- updating the JRE (8u101)

and I don't know what else to try to resolve this.

This is the error in the `gradle` console with `--stacktrace` `--debug`:

```
08:33:16.858 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
08:33:16.858 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
08:33:16.858 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
08:33:16.858 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
08:33:16.858 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
08:33:16.858 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
08:33:16.858 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
08:33:16.858 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] java.lang.NullPointerException
08:33:16.858 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TreeSnapshotRepository.removeTreeSnapshotUsage(TreeSnapshotRepository.java:85)
08:33:16.858 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedFileSnapshotRepository.remove(CacheBackedFileSnapshotRepository.java:47)
08:33:16.858 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$1$1.run(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:84)
08:33:16.858 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
08:33:16.859 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:192)
08:33:16.859 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
08:33:16.859 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
08:33:16.859 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
08:33:16.859 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:60)
08:33:16.859 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$1.update(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:66)
08:33:16.859 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.afterTask(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:135)
08:33:16.859 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:68)
08:33:16.859 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
08:33:16.859 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
08:33:16.859 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
08:33:16.859 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
08:33:16.859 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
08:33:16.859 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
08:33:16.860 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
08:33:16.861 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
08:33:16.862 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
08:33:16.862 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
08:33:16.862 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
08:33:16.862 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
08:33:16.862 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
08:33:16.862 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
08:33:16.862 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
08:33:16.862 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
08:33:16.863 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
08:33:16.863 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
08:33:16.863 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
08:33:16.863 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
08:33:16.863 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
08:33:16.863 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
08:33:16.864 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
08:33:16.864 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
08:33:16.864 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
08:33:16.864 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
08:33:16.864 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
08:33:16.864 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
08:33:16.864 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
08:33:16.864 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
08:33:16.864 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
08:33:16.864 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use latest `2.2.0` gradle build tools  in app `build.gradle` file.

Comment: you are having build exception did you miss any dependency?

Comment: When I installed Android Studio 2.2, it prompted me to update gradle to 2.2.0 and I accepted. It worked fine until Android Studio crashed. In my `build.gradle` it says 2.2.0, but in my `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle` directory there is only 2.14.1. I think the dependency got corrupt somewhere. How do I force it to redo the update to 2.2.0?

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I am also facing this issue.

Comment: I went to the point of uninstalling Android Studio, the SDK, deleting the `C:\Users\user\.AndroidStudio2.2` and `C:\Users\user\.gradle` folders, as well as the `C:\Program Files\Android` folder. Then reinstalled it all from scratch and tried to run the app, but it still says the same thing. So it seems to be something inside the project, but I don't know what.

Comment: In Android Studio, I've now gone to `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle`, and switched it from "Use local gradle distribution" (which is set to `c:\program files\android\android studio\gradle\gradle-2.14.1`) to "use default gradle wrapper (recommended)", then clicked "okay". It seems to be downloading and Android Studio says "refreshing 'app' Gradle project", so I'll wait and report back when it is done, on whether it fixes it.

Comment: if nothing else is working, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52462269/1008011), it could be your gradle.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing I tried on the Android Studio/SDK side worked.

So I had to do the manual route. I:

- went to the `AndroidStudioProjects` directory and manually changed the name (just added "-backup" to the end of the directory name);
- made a new project in Android Studio with the original project name and package name, then closed Android Studio;
- returned to `AndroidStudioProjects` directory and copied the dependencies section in the backup `[project]\app\build.gradle` file to the same file in the new project;
- copied the `[project]\app\src\main` directory with everything inside from the old project to the new one;
- opened Android Studio and selected `Build > Rebuild Project`
- then just ran the project and it worked.

Now to start fixing the VCS... -_-!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that if you have local.properties, the paths for sdk.dir and ndk.dir (if defined) actually exist.  In my case, my project wasn't using ndk, however my local.properties was copied from a project that was, and the ndk directory was not valid.  I didn't think it would have mattered, but i downloaded and extracted the ndk into the path in the local.properties, and now it works.  I suppose i could have just as easily commented / deleted the line in local.properties, but that wouldn't have been as much fun.. :)