# Unit test configuration broke in Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, junit, android-gradle-plugin

I updated to Android Studio 3.1 and as suggested by Android Studio also:

- Updated the Android gradle plugin to 3.1.0 from 2.3.0 (also tried the new 3.1.1, the problem persists)
- Updated the buildToolsVersion to 27.0.3
- Downloaded the Android 8.1 API 27 with the SDK manager.

I am using the JDK 8.

My previous Android Studio build configuration "Core tests" which just ran all tests in one module now says:

> Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5.1-all.zip'.

My set up:
[image]

The exact exception as shown in the ide:
[image]

My full source code:
https://github.com/Leejjon/BluffPoker

Apparently the same Nullpointer occurs when running this on the command line: `gradle :core:test` This command will fail with the same NullPointer. Doing a test on the root project like `gradle test` will run fine. I can also deploy the app on my Android phone. This is probably not IntelliJ related but the Android gradle plugin 3.1.0 breaking the ability to run the `gradle :core:test` command.

TLDR: Running any gradle task in the core module like `gradle :core:sometask` seems to result in a null pointer since Android gradle plugin 3.1.0.

My workaround for now is to use the `gradle test` command to run all tests in all modules and study the generated html pages by junit (found in BluffPoker\core\build\reports\tests\test\index.html) to troubleshoot whether they are failing.

Comment: Try downgrading Gradle version in gradle.properties? https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle

Comment: I was already using this gradle version before this upgrade and it worked fine. I'd prefer finding a solution that gets Android Studio to work with it.

Comment: Well, your  error is clearly complaining about that Gradle version. And the documentation says Gradle plugin 3.1 supports 4.4+, so just try it

Comment: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`

Comment: try [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52462269/1008011) your gradle.properties and then re-enabling configure on demand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this bug commenter pointed out:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77605097#comment7

disabling the "configure on demand" feature of Gradle (in Settings: Build, Execution, and Deployment: Compiler) is a viable workaround.

Since I did this my Unit tests are all working again.

Answer (score 1):

Solution from kekkou of the libgdx forums:
http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=27639&p=109249#p109249

His solution is: Move the `project(':android') {}` block in root build.gradle into android\build.gradle.

This makes all commands work again. I did not find any downsides.

The commit for this fix on my project:
https://github.com/Leejjon/BluffPoker/commit/d10deb090c2d80e641d733efdaa85f99c0a9fe2f

Answer (score 0):

in your gradle-wrapper.properties, try using:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-rc-2-all.zip

Comment: Why use an RC build, when actual later releases exist?

Comment: I am getting:
Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.4. Current version is 4.3-rc-2.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project
Gradle settings

Comment: @Leejjon click on it then and fix.

Comment: @Whitebear clicking it will change the gradle wrapper properties to 4.4 again, which will result in the same error as when I use 4.5.1 (as I added to the first post: https://i.imgur.com/oa4VH5F.png).