# Android, Gradle : java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have tried all the solutions provide in below stackoverflow question But none of these work for me.

[java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183674/java-lang-nullpointerexception-no-error-message)

Here,I have attached the logs file for further information.Please help me if any one knows.I am really struggling with these.Thanks.

- Gradle version : 4.4
- Android Plugin version : 3.1.3

[Log file for the exception](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jumjgf0MGrIIijxlL3229Vd2NUpTSRL6TQfoG086tsY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Solved : Android Studio --> Preferences --> Build,Execution,Deployment : uncheck Configure on demand Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554589/unit-test-configuration-broke-in-android-studio-3-1

Answer (score 0):

Solve it by `Android Studio --> Preferences --> Build, Execution, Deployment` and then unchecking `Configure on demand`

[Unit test configuration broke in Android Studio 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554589/unit-test-configuration-broke-in-android-studio-3-1)