# what is the problem and how can i solve it?

Tags: flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 46s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183674/java-lang-nullpointerexception-no-error-message)

Answer (score 0):

his Problem was created when the suddenly System restarted, then the gradle file corrupted. and that corrupted file cached, so we need to Delete this file from your project
delete.gradle folder from the project and rebuild it again.

N.B: Make a backup, just in case.

Comment: delete .gradle folder from the project and was able to rebuild it again.