# Android Studio / Gradle errors

Tags: java, android, gradle

My project worked just fine, and out of a sudden when I tried to rebuild it, I got these errors:

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,  :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :buttonstyle:generateDebugSources, :buttonstyle:mockableAndroidJar, :buttonstyle:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :buttonstyle:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
>
> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

This is my build gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ba.application.travel"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11"
            }
        }
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.0.1'
    compile project(':buttonstyle')

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.ashokvarma.android:bottom-navigation-bar:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.4.2@aar'
    compile 'com.github.grennis:ExpandableRecyclerView:0.9.3'
    compile 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}

Comment: Use this and rebuild the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing an image format from .jpg to .png

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling multidex support. Refer the below link to know the steps to enable multidex support in your project.
[Enabling multidex support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925264/android-support-multidex-library-implementation)

Comment: I enabled the multidex support, but no effect. I still get the same errors.