# MultiDex for Android 4.2

Tags: android, xamarin, android-multidex

I have a Xamarin project that has been working for some time.  We recently (a few months ago) had to enable `MultiDex`.  For some reason yesterday it started to refuse to work on devices with Android 4.2.  This had been working fine and I'm not sure what changed to affect it.  We are seeing this message in the Android log:

```
> 01-10 08:12:09.903 E/AndroidRuntime(20781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 01-10 08:12:09.903 E/AndroidRuntime(20781):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
> mono.android.app.Application: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't
> find class "mono.android.app.Application" on path:
> /data/app/com.afs.dsd_mobile-1.apk
```

From what I can tell this is due to the application class being listed in the wrong `classes.dex` file.  This is based on what I read here:
http://www.jon-douglas.com/2016/09/05/xamarin-android-multidex/

However, when I modify the `mainClassesDex.bat` as suggested, it does not fix the problem.  Am I missing something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925264/android-support-multidex-library-implementation

Comment: Have you tried using `android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication` for your `MultiDex` as mentioned in the blog you posted?

Comment: Seeing that it's trying to find `mono.android.app.Application` on the dex list, it suggests what Elvis Xia is suggesting and also that you may not have the proper startup classes defined in your `classes.dex`(Main dex list). You can view my blog on how to override those values. http://www.jon-douglas.com/2016/09/23/xamarin-android-multidex-keep/

Please note that the simplest way to get a general idea for your `multidex.keep` file is to let it generate as per normal and then copy that into your custom `multidex.keep`. You can then add/subtract which classes you need in the main list.

Answer (score 1):

This article works for me: 
https://przemekraciborski.eu/2016/09/30/multidex-in-xamarin

Add new text file to project (ex. multidex.keep), set it’s build action to “MutliDexMainDexList”:

```
md526383ae8de55e54b0b30f6a8bd5184a3\ThisApplication.class
md576a02dcd2afe330a5b70333d32546ae9\LoginActivity.class
mono/android/app/ApplicationRegistration.class
mono/android/app/NotifyTimeZoneChanges.class
mono/MonoRuntimeProvider.class
mono/MonoPackageManager.class
mono/MonoPackageManager_Resources.class
```